# list members can be accessed with partial name? Is this a feature?

Tags: r

Consider this R code

```
> l = list(key = 1)
> l$k
[1] 1
> l$ke
[1] 1
> l[['k']]
NULL
> names(l)
[1] "key"
```

Does this mean that you can access a list member with `$` and its partial name?  I couldn't believe my eyes when I discovered this after a frustrating bug-hunting.

Is this a feature of R list?  Is there a name for it? Is it possible to turn it off?  This causes obvious troubles when you use it like a Python dict.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a feature that is meant to help in interactive mode.  You can tighten it locally, see `help(options)` which has

```
 ‘warnPartialMatchArgs’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used in argument matching.

 ‘warnPartialMatchAttr’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used in extracting attributes via ‘attr’.

 ‘warnPartialMatchDollar’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used for extraction by ‘$’.
```

Example:

```
R> l <- list(key = 1)
R> l$k
[1] 1
R> options("warnPartialMatchDollar"=TRUE)
R> l$k
[1] 1
Warning message:
In l$k : partial match of 'k' to 'key'
R>
```

and you can further promote warnings to errors if you so choose (and that option is described on the same page).

Comment: It is absolutely terrifying that this feature is there, and it's even more terrifying that it's a global option. What were they thinking. This feature is dangerous. It can end up silently feeding incorrect numbers into equations.

Comment: I agree @StefanoBorini. When I learned about this, I was totally terrified.

Comment: more than a decade of R and I just discover this...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `$` will do partial matching. Check the R document of the $ function by typing in the console

```
?`$`
```

In the help document it says:

> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does. `x$name` is
>   equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the exact argument.

According to Hadley Wickham's book "Advanced R", you can turn off the partial matching of `$` by setting the global option `warnPartialMatchDollar` to `TRUE`, but it may affect behavior in other code you have loaded, e.g. from a package.

Comment: I'm a newbie to stack overflow trying to answer an unanswered question. It took me 20 minutes to read and understandthe question, come up with my solution, double check it in R and carefully write down my answer. Sorry I didn't come up with an answer as fast and thorough as yours. I'll try to be better next time.

Comment: Fair but it still pretty redundant now.  We've all come late here too.