# How to make R stop accepting partial matches for column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I recently had a difficult time chasing down a bug in my code -- it turned out I was referencing a column that did not exist, but R was not giving me any kind of error or warning about referencing a non-existent column. Instead, because the non-existent column I referenced happened to match the beginning of the name of another column, R was silently substituting that other column.

I find that to be a very undesirable behavior -- what does R call it, and how do I turn it off?

Example:

```
> a <- as.data.frame(cbind(rep(0,5),rep(2,5),seq(58,62)))
> colnames(a) <- c('eligible','height','age_of_death')
> a
  eligible height age_of_death
1        0      2           58
2        0      2           59
3        0      2           60
4        0      2           61
5        0      2           62
> a$he
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
> a$eligible[a$age >= 60] <- 1
> a
  eligible height age_of_death
1        0      2           58
2        0      2           59
3        1      2           60
4        1      2           61
5        1      2           62
```

Not sure if all versions of R do this or not, but I'm using 3.6.0.

How do I disable this feature so R will tell me if I reference a non-existent column instead of trying to substitute a similarly-named column for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525972/r-list-members-can-be-accessed-with-partial-name-is-this-a-feature

Comment: This surprises me, although I *did* know that function argument names can be partially matched.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `a` to a tibble seems to throw an Warning message, not sure if this is enough for you

```
library(dplyr)
a < - as_tibble(a)
a$eligible[a$age >= 60] <- 1
# Warning message:
# Unknown or uninitialised column: 'age'.
```

If you are not familiar with tibbles you can look at the doc [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html).

Edit:
Another solution seems to use bracket notation instead of dollar

```
a$eligible[a["age"] >= 60] <- 1
# Error in `[.data.frame`(a, "age") : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea base R did that. Another plus for the Tidyverse, I guess.